# Conditionals and relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, conditionals

Some questions about the second conditional and relative clauses.

---

(My friend is eating a popsicle.)

> (1) Me: If I had money on me, I would buy a popsicle you **are** eating right now.

> (revised) Me: If I had money on me, I would buy the same popsicle you **are** eating right now.

Is the **are** correct here?

---

> (2) Me: If I had the money that Bill Gates **has**, I would buy a mansion you **see** in luxury magazines.

> (revised) Me: If I had the money that Bill Gates **has**, I would buy the type of mansion you **see** in luxury magazines.

Is the **has** correct here?

Is the **see** correct here?

---

> (3) Me: If I had the money that Bill Gates **has**, I would build a mansion that **would amaze** you.

Is the **has** correct here?

Is the **would amaze** correct here?

---

So in a relative clause that modifies a noun in a conditional sentence, if we are talking about real things, we don't need to change the verbs into "would + verb" and just use the verbs normally depending on what we are talking about, but if we are talking about hypothetical things, we use "would + verb". Am I right?

Comment: (1) _like the one you are eating_. You don't want to buy the half-eaten one! Similarly in (2), _like the ones you see..._

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for your corrections. I see the weird parts of my examples. I have revised them. So what do you think about the use of tenses in the revised examples?

Comment: Yes, the tenses are fine.